Make it easier to add, change, and update pages on existing WP website
We're an all-volunteer nonprofit with a 70+ page WordPress website in each of 3 languages: https://www.kotorkitties.org.  We're happy with the look and content we have, but struggle to add new content, or change text of pictures. The volunteer who set it up moved on to other things.
We're advised to install a Divi "theme" for simpler drag and drop editing, but I'm unclear why we need a new theme if we're happy with what we have.  Would the Divi Builder do what we need-- to make editing easier for dummies?
Thanks!

Welcome to WPSE. We're a community of developers helping out each other with specific coding issues. Unfortunately your question is too general for our format and not really answerable without knowledge of your specific backoffice.

What exact problems are you encountering when you try to add new content?

If you're happy with how it looks already, then installing a new theme, as you suggested, isn't what you're after. This sounds moreso like 'learning to use' what you already have so you can keep adding content.  Adding Divi may invalidate or adversely impact all of the content you already have in place, which you like.  Looks as though the site is built with https://wordpress.org/themes/sinatra/ so you should just review documentation on how to use the Block Editor.  https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/wordpress-block-editor/
